# How to loop through table cells in the same row with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this table, which is always going to have one row:

```
<table id="contractCoverablesGrid" width="600" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var coverableItem in Model.ContractCoverablesList)
            {
                <td>
                    <div id="dataListItem">
                        @Html.Hidden("coverableID", coverableItem.CoverID)
                        @Html.Label(coverableItem.Name)
                        @Html.CheckBox("coverableItemCheckBox", coverableItem.IsApplied)
                    </div>
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to be able to loop through every cell, find out if the checkbox is checked, then capture the ID in that cell, which is as you see a hidden field.

I have tried to do this, but the problem is that when it reaches the if clause; it doesn't detected the checked box:

```
//Coverable Items
var count = 0;
var allCoverableItems = [];
$("#contractCoverablesGrid tbody tr td").each(function () {
    var cell = $(this);

    var coverableItem = {};

    if (cell.find('td input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) { // Here, it doesn't detect checked boxes!!
        var coverableId = cell.find("input[name='coverableID']")[count].value;

        coverableItem["CoverID"] = coverableId;
        allCoverableItems.push(coverableItem);
    }
    count++;
});
```

I wonder what is wrong here - I am a bit new to JQuery/Javascript.

Many thanks.

**Edit**

This is the working code:

```
//Coverable Items
var allCoverableItems = [];
$("#contractCoverablesGrid tbody tr td").each(function () {
    var cell = $(this);

    var coverableItem = {};

    if (cell.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        var coverableId = cell.find("input[name='coverableID']").val();

        coverableItem["CoverID"] = coverableId;
        allCoverableItems.push(coverableItem);
    }
});
```

I removed the count and followed the answer below, plus; I used val() instead of value;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is with your selector.  You are searching for a td within `cell`, but `cell` already is a td.  Change it to this:

```
cell.find('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

You'll also have trouble with the next line, when you try to access the hidden field via `[count]`.  It looks like when you started writing this code, you intended to act on the row, but at some point chose to iterate the cells instead.  The next line should be:

```
var coverableId = cell.find("input[name='coverableID']").val();
```